# Roomle SDK in Rails 6, using webpacker, throws errors

Tags: roomle

Using instructions on [roomle github page](https://github.com/Roomle/web-sdk) how to setup web SDK I'm getting JS errors in console and cofigurator is not rendered inside canvas.

Init script:

```
window.__RML__ENV__ = {
  assetPath: '/roomle_assets/'
};

import RoomleSdk from '@roomle/web-sdk';

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', async function () {
  const scene = document.getElementById("scene");
  const roomleConfigurator = await RoomleSdk.getConfigurator();
  roomleConfigurator.boot();
  await roomleConfigurator.getApi().init(scene);
  await roomleConfigurator.getApi().loadConfigurableItemById('item:id');
});
```

Assets are loaded and placed correctly. First error is shown on `roomleConfigurator.boot()` and for other I'm not sure.

Webpack compiles all files correctly and this is only code that is included alongside required packages from Rails itself.

When using example from documentation https://docs.roomle.com/web/guides/tutorial/glbviewer/ for GLB viewer implementation only second error is shown. `Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object animateCamera pixotron-539caf55.js:502 ...`

Errors are rather long so here is the link with .txt and corresponding screenshots with specific lines that errors refer to. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E75ox8dWfxoo8wBoe-UlMUgIorUIqM1Z/view?usp=sharing

I'm uising @roomle/web-sdk version version 2.5.0

Comment: Can you try what happens if you transpile to ES6 instead of ES5? It seems like the transpilation step causes troubles. Roomle Rubens officially supports modern browsers so ES6 would be fine. For more details see: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#some-notes-on-the-example

Comment: @tschoartschi you are right. It was a transpile issue. Just have to figure out if it's possible to implement through Rails webpacker or do we need to create external client app.

Comment: I'm glad my hint helped you to find the root cause of the problem. I hope you can figure out how to configure the Rails webpacker to produce the needed ES version. Just let me know if you need further help :-)